# Virtualenv, Django and PyCharm. File structure

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pycharm

I am newbie using VirtualEnv and recently try to create one using PyCharm. During the process, PyCharm ask me to specify the project location, application name and VirtualEnv name and location. My doubt is, after I specify the name and location of the VirtualEnv the location of the Django project files must be inside the VirtualEnv? or it's possible to have the VirtualEnv files in a different location than the Django project files?

Maybe I am not understanding the purpose of the VirtualEnv. Perhaps, VirtualEnv it's just a list of the dependencies of my project, Python version, Django version, Pip version, Jinja2 version and all other required files, but not necessarily the Django application files (the website that is being developed).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya, I think you misunderstand what `virtualenv` does:

https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/

> The basic problem being addressed is one of dependencies and versions, and indirectly permissions. Imagine you have an application that needs version 1 of LibFoo, but another application requires version 2. How can you use both these applications? If you install everything into /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (or whatever your platform’s standard location is), it’s easy to end up in a situation where you unintentionally upgrade an application that shouldn’t be upgraded.

Your project files don't need to be (and shouldn't be) where the `virtualenv` files are.

`virtualenv` installs your app's python dependancies in a folder for the specific `virtualenv` that is being used.

Let's say you are not using `virtualenv`, the dependencies would be installed into into the site-packages folder for your system. The dependancies aren't installed in your project directory and your project directory isn't in your system's site-packages directory.

Using `virtualenv` doesn't change that, it just changes where the dependencies are installed.

Comment: Thanks @DTing for your help. It makes sense now. You are right, if I don't use VirtualEnv I am not going to put the files of the website that I am developing inside of the system site-packages directory. That's absurd. Thats why PyCharm IDE asked me where I want to put the VirtualEnv folder (to contain and isolate all my dependencies) and where the files generated by Django (my website).

Answer (score 1):

`virtualenv` is not just a list of dependencies! It actually has all the modules under its umbrella. Think of a `virtualenv` as a space which isolates all the packages used by your project from the rest of the other packages that were installed previously or at a later time.Yes, there is an option to have the `virtualenv` make use of packages that are "outside" of the environment but that's just an option.
The main purpose of having an `virtualenv` is to enable the user to use packages versions of his choice and keep them isolated from the rest of the space. Usually, the list of packages belonging to a specific `virtualenv` are captured into a file, `requirements.txt`. If you want to run the project on a different machine or share it with someone, having `requirements.txt` will make it easy to recreate the environment via `pip install -r requirement.txt` from within `virtualenv`